# Liferay 7.3 How to Search only Content of JournalArticles?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-7.3

```java
SearchUtil.search(
                Collections.emptyMap(),
                booleanQuery -> {
                    BooleanFilter booleanFilter =
                            booleanQuery.getPreBooleanFilter();
                    booleanFilter.add(
                            new TermFilter(Field.GROUP_ID, String.valueOf(siteId)),
                            BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);
                    booleanFilter.add(
                            new TermFilter(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_NAME, JournalArticle.class.getName()),
                            BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);
                },
                filter, JournalArticle.class, search, pagination,
                queryConfig -> queryConfig.setSelectedFieldNames(
                        Field.ARTICLE_ID),
                searchContext -> {
                    searchContext.setVulcanCheckPermissions(true);
                    searchContext.addVulcanAggregation(aggregation);
                    searchContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
                    searchContext.setAttribute("ddmStructureKey", "myDDMStructure");
                },
                sort,
                document -> MyParserUtil.wrapArticle(JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticle(siteId, document.get(Field.ARTICLE_ID)))
        );
```

This is my code, I have issue regarding search. At the moment, search is working with FULL-TEXT like I want but it looks all fields in JournalArticle table and also all fields inside content field (`DDMStructure`).

I want to limit search to look only fields Title and Description inside Content (`DDMStructure`).

I tried with this:

```java
QueryFilter query = ddmIndexer.createFieldValueQueryFilter(myDDMStructure, MyDDMStructure.Description.name(), contextCompany.getLocale(), search);
```

and adding it inside `booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST)` but in that case if my description is "My Description Test" and search is "My Description XXXX", it wont match because the third word is not matching. I want to look at it as a FULL-TEXT index and to give best results (thats how it works without this additional query.

I tried with `DDMIndexer` and I am getting some progress but its still not what I am looking for. I described in previous section in detail. I already saw some comments with documentation links, some of them pages are removed and some of them I tried but i did not get what I want.